# 'FirebaseApplication' object has no attribute 'Authentication'

Tags: firebase-authentication, raspberry-pi3

I'm using the following code to fetch data from Firebase on Raspberry pi but it shows following error. However i'm able to fetch data without authentication.

```
    from firebase.firebase import FirebaseApplication
    from firebase.firebase import FirebaseAuthentication
    firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://myapp.firebaseio.com/', 
    authentication =None)
    authentication = firebase.Authentication('secretkey', 
    'prateekrai266@gmail.com', extra={'id': 123})
    firebase.authentication = authentication
    print (authentication.extra)
    user = authentication.get_user()
    print (user.firebase_auth_token)
    result = firebase.get('/messages', None)
```

it shows following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/home/pi/code/dataauth.py", line 7, in  authentication =
>   firebase.Authentication('secretkey',  'prateekrai266@gmail.com',
>   extra={'id': 123}) AttributeError: 'FirebaseApplication' object has no
>   attribute  'Authentication'

I'm able to fetch data without authentication i.e. setting rules to true, by following code

```
from firebase.firebase import FirebaseApplication
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://myapp.firebaseio.com/', 
None)
result = firebase.get('/messages', None)
```

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are using python-firebase which is a bit deprecated and not updated for long time. I've tried to fix your problem, found solution for your issue, but problem with authenticating still occurs.

Code:

```
from firebase.firebase import FirebaseApplication
from firebase.firebase import FirebaseAuthentication
DSN = config['databaseURL'] # 'https://myapp.firebaseio.com/'
SECRET = config['userPass'] # 'secretkey'
EMAIL =config['userEmail'] # 'prateekrai266@gmail.com'

authentication = FirebaseAuthentication(SECRET,EMAIL, True, True)
firebase = FirebaseApplication(DSN, authentication)

firebase.get('/messages', None)
```

I would suggest to move into `pyrebase` which is more updated and as I've just checked works.

https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase

Code that works for me:

```
import pyrebase
config = {
    'apiKey': "YYY",
    'authDomain': "XXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com",
    'databaseURL': "https://XXXXXXXX.firebaseio.com",
    'projectId': "XXXXXXXX",
    'storageBucket': "XXXXXXXX.appspot.com",
    'messagingSenderId': "ZZZ",
}
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)

userEmail = 'youremailadresthatyouaddedtofirebasedatabaseauthenticatedusers'
userPass = 'yourpasswordsetupforthisemail'

auth = firebase.auth()

# Log the user in
user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(userEmail, userPass)

# Get a reference to the database service
db = firebase.database()

# data to save
data = {
            "name": "Mortimer 'Morty' Smith"
            }

# Pass the user's idToken to the push method
results = db.child("test").push(data, user['idToken'])
print results
results = db.child("test").get(user['idToken'])
print results.val()
```